# What exactly is mask band according to GDAL?

Tags: gdal, digital-image-processing, extract-by-mask

The GDAL [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#index-0) for the translate function says:

Select an input band to create an output dataset mask band. But what exactly is a mask band?

band can be set to *"none"* to avoid copying the global mask of the input dataset if it exists. The global mask is the mask of all bands?

Otherwise, it is copied by default (*"auto"*), unless the mask is an alpha channel, or if it is explicitly used to be a regular band of the output dataset (*"-b mask"*). What is an alpha channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask bands are described in the documentation:

- https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc15_nodatabitmask.html
- https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#internal-nodata-masks